# Recursive function in async tree in php gets with "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728"

Tags: php, function, memory, tree, out-of-memory

i have tried to do an async tree but when i call a function inside the function she get me an memory error. I have read many things how to change the limit of the php memory to run that and i tried that and it doesn't result. But what i realy want is a way to "stop" the function, to not call that infinitely times. Can anyone help me?

```
function treeview()
{    
    $i = 0;
    $result = array();
    $rs = mysql_query("select * from dados3 where nivel = 1");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
    {
        $node = array();
        $node['id'] = $row['id'];
        $node['text'] = $row['descricao'];
        $node['state'] = 'closed';
        $node['children'] = has_child($row['id']);
        array_push($result, $node);
    }  
echo json_encode($result);
}

function has_child($id){

    $result2 = array();
    $node_2 = array();
    $rs = mysql_query("select * from dados3 where id_nivel_superior=$id");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
    $node_2['text'] = $row['descricao'];
    $node_2['state'] = 'closed';
    $node_2['children'] = has_child($id);
    array_push($result2, $node_2);
    return $result2;
}
```

I tried the above way and that returns me all the children null and at level 3 repeats me the level 1. What you think it can be wrong?

```
function treeview()
{    
    $i = 0;
    $result = array();
    $rs = mysql_query("select * from dados3 where nivel = 1");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
    {
        $node = array();
        $node['id'] = $row['id'];
        $node['text'] = $row['descricao'];
        $node['state'] = 'closed';
        $node['children'] = has_child($row['id']);
        array_push($result, $node);
    }  
echo json_encode($result);
}

function has_child($id){

    $result2 = array();
    $node_2 = array();
    $rs = mysql_query("select * from dados3 where id_nivel_superior=$id");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
    {
        $node_2['text'] = $row['descricao'];
        $node_2['state'] = 'closed';
        $node_2['children'] = has_child($row['id']);
        array_push($result2, $node_2);
        return $result2;
    }
}
```

Here at the image you can see the database structure anda data:

[image of database](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z6ftuy33oxumx3e/untitled.JPG)

I have already put the return out of the loop but the json that returns me it's with the cildren all null. And at level 4 (where i want to show something) it continuos repeatedly all the levels again.

```
[{"id":"1","text":"1 - Cat.","state":"closed","children":[{"text":"1.1 - Sub.","state":"closed","children":[]},{"text":"1.2 - Sub.","state":"closed","children":[]},{"text":"1.3 - Sub.","state":"closed","children":[]}]},{"id":"2","text":"2 - Cat.","state":"closed","children":[{"text":"2.1 - Sub.","state":"closed","children":[{"text":"2.1.1 - Sub_sub","state":"closed","children":[{"text":"Faq 1 - categoria 1","state":"closed","children":[]}]}]},{"text":"2.2 - Sub.","state":"closed","children":[]},{"text":"2.3 - Sub.","state":"closed","children":[]}]},{"id":"4","text":"3- Cat.","state":"closed","children":[{"text":"3.1 - Sub.","state":"closed","children":[]},{"text":"3.2 - Sub.","state":"closed","children":[]},{"text":"3.3 - Sub.","state":"closed","children":[]}]},{"id":"5","text":"4 - Cat.","state":"closed","children":[{"text":"4.1 - Sub.","state":"closed","children":[]},{"text":"4.2 - Sub.","state":"closed","children":[]},{"text":"4.3 - Sub.","state":"closed","children":[]}]}]
```

If you can help me understand why the children doesn't appears i will appreciate.

Best regards.

Comment: has_child calls has_child and has_child calls has_child...inf loop also a obligatory suggestion, [**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is your recursive call to has_child() is passing in $id, i.e. the parameter originally passed to the function. So, what's happening is because the function is being called with the same parameter every time, it will recursively call itself endlessly.

I suspect the line

```
$node_2['children'] = has_child($id);
```

should actually read

```
$node_2['children'] = has_child($row['id']);
```

Also, I suspect you probably want a loop in has_child() as well, in the same way as in treeview() otherwise you'll only get the first item at each level of the tree.

EDIT

Actually, sorry, I may have misunderstood what's going on here. Earlier I assumed that "id_nivel_superior" was the parent item's ID, but am I right in saying that actually that's the parent's level within the tree? If so, is there something that does contain the parent item's ID, as that's the column your SQL statement in has_child() needs to use. It might help if you could post your table structure and a sample of your data.

Also, your return statement in has_child() needs to be outside the loop.

OK, to answer your latest edit, I might be missing something here, but it looks like the JSON output you've posted is correct according to the data you have. Its a bit tricky to read on one line, but if you run it through the formatter at http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ you'll see this is what it looks like:

```
[
   {
      "id":"1",
      "text":"1 - Cat.",
      "state":"closed",
      "children":[
         {
            "text":"1.1 - Sub.",
            "state":"closed",
            "children":[

            ]
         },
         {
            "text":"1.2 - Sub.",
            "state":"closed",
            "children":[

            ]
         },
         {
            "text":"1.3 - Sub.",
            "state":"closed",
            "children":[

            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"2",
      "text":"2 - Cat.",
      "state":"closed",
      "children":[
         {
            "text":"2.1 - Sub.",
            "state":"closed",
            "children":[
               {
                  "text":"2.1.1 - Sub_sub",
                  "state":"closed",
                  "children":[
                     {
                        "text":"Faq 1 - categoria 1",
                        "state":"closed",
                        "children":[

                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "text":"2.2 - Sub.",
            "state":"closed",
            "children":[

            ]
         },
         {
            "text":"2.3 - Sub.",
            "state":"closed",
            "children":[

            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"4",
      "text":"3- Cat.",
      "state":"closed",
      "children":[
         {
            "text":"3.1 - Sub.",
            "state":"closed",
            "children":[

            ]
         },
         {
            "text":"3.2 - Sub.",
            "state":"closed",
            "children":[

            ]
         },
         {
            "text":"3.3 - Sub.",
            "state":"closed",
            "children":[

            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"5",
      "text":"4 - Cat.",
      "state":"closed",
      "children":[
         {
            "text":"4.1 - Sub.",
            "state":"closed",
            "children":[

            ]
         },
         {
            "text":"4.2 - Sub.",
            "state":"closed",
            "children":[

            ]
         },
         {
            "text":"4.3 - Sub.",
            "state":"closed",
            "children":[

            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

which as far as I can tell matches the database. If there's something not right about this then can you please let me know what output you're expecting to get?